# Minimizing the difference between two prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I tried to somehow simplify the statement to find $(q-p)$ but I couldn't.
Here is the question:

> Given that $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers with $p<q$ and given that  $pq-p-q = 59$,
>   what is the smallest value of $q-p$?

Please help me and explain how to solve this question.

Comment: How about 1 as in $(3-2)$? To be honest, I'm not quite sure what you're really asking.

Comment: for some reason it did not publish my question properly, here is the question :p and q are prime numbers and p is less than q : p<q
knowing the statement : p*q -q-p =59 ,
what is the smallest value for q-p?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question accordingly then? To format the equations, I'd suggest that you visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: there is no bracket anywhere , this is a simple multiplication and to subtractions. p*q-q-p=59

Comment: @user291693-Ok....understood...

Comment: Interesting side-note: $pq-p-q$ is the Frobenius number, aka chicken mcnuggests number, for any coprome pair p,q of coin values.

Answer (score 5):

If $pq - p - q=59$, then $(p-1)(q-1)=pq-p-q+1=59+1=60$

Splitting $60$ into pairs of factors, we might get:
$$\begin{align*}
60&=1\cdot 60 \implies p=2, q=61 ; q-p=59\\
60&=2\cdot 30 \implies p=3, q=31 ; q-p=28\\
60&=3\cdot 20 \implies p=4, q=21 ; \ (\text{not prime})\\
60&=4\cdot 15 \implies p=5, q=16 ; \ (\text{not prime})\\
60&=5\cdot 12 \implies p=6, q=13 ; \ (\text{not prime})\\
60&=6\cdot 10 \implies p=7, q=11 ; q-p=4\\
60&=10\cdot 6 \implies p>q
\end{align*}
$$

The lowest difference happens clearly for the last case, so $p=7$ and $q=11$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more rigorous approach, which still involves a little trial-and-error. Note that $pq-p-q=59$ can be rewritten $$(1-p)(1-q)-1=59 \Rightarrow (1-p)(1-q)=60$$Clearly, with $p$ and $q$ both primes in $\mathbb{N}$, the factors $a,b$ of $60$ given by $(1-p)$ and $(1-q)$ respectively must be negative integers. This leaves the following cases for $(a,b)$: $$(-1,-60),(-2,-30),(-3,-20),(-4,-15),(-5,-12),(-6,-10)$$Checking each of these gives $(-6,-10)$ with the lowest value of $p-q$ since $a=-6,b=-10 \Rightarrow p=7, q=11 \Rightarrow q-p=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $pq-p-q=59$ for prime numbers $p,q$ when $q=11$ and $p=7$.

$11*7-11-7$

$=77-18$

$=59.$.

Rigorous Proof:-
$pq-p-q=59$

After adding $+1$ on both sides and taking common we get,

$(p-1)(q-1)=60$

Solving this equation yields the answer.

**Point to note is that there is no unique answer.So, goal should be to find consecutive primes so that difference is the least.**

So, the smallest value of $q-p$ is $11-7=4.$

Comment: "clearly..." While, yes, brute force checking can get an answer, how do you propose to find the values $11$ and $7$ without plugging it into wolfram alpha?

Comment: It would be interesting if we have a well mathematically done procedure, so that this result can be generalized even when $p$ and $q$ are unknown.

Comment: @JMoravitz-By intuition.....if you call that intuition to find two prime numbers....

Comment: But 11,7 are not the only pair of primes (another is 31,3). To me one needs to prove this example does give the least difference.

Comment: @coffeemath-OP asked for least difference...

Comment: how can you prove that 11 and 7 are unique answers to the question ? your answer is based on educated guess, please provide a proof.

Comment: You need to prove that $(11, 7)$ is the pair that minimizes the difference, you cannot produce it out of thin air and say "Clearly".

Comment: tatan: I understand OP wants least difference, but my point was your answer didn't *prove* that 11,7 gives least difference.

Comment: @user291693-It's never mentioned unique.Its the pair with least difference as no other prime before this satisfies it.....by the way,it would have been better if you told me where you find the question....if this is an MCQ type....

Comment: @tatan But you didn't prove that $(11, 7)$ has such a property, you simply stated it, which isn't sufficient.

Comment: @coffeemath-No previous prime pairs satisfy it...if you want a rigorous proof,I would try to do that...this is not a rigorous one clearly...